# Overflow on div makes it appear above fixed menu

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I have a fixed menu at the top with a z-index of 999 (to stop anything appearing in front of it in theory). I also have a div that is designed to scroll horizontally. Why are the overflow properties on the scrolling div making it appear on top of the menu bar?

Scrolling div CSS:

```
.product-viewer {
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3vmax;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3vmax;
    height: 300px;
    height: 30vmax;
    background-color: #202020;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Menu bar CSS (#menu.fix is when the menu is fixed as it is a "sticky" menu):

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    height: 5vmax;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background-blend-mode: hard-light;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 50px;
    line-height: 5vmax;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu.fix {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Link to site: https://www.inquaress.com/ranges/beach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.cover-image` element has `z-index: 0 !important;` and that makes it flow under the following element. You should check your markup as your menu is a child element of `.cover-image` and your following element `.section.no-select` doesn't have `z-index` definitions thus interpreted by the browser to go over the previous element.

Your fix would be just to change your z-index something like

```
.cover-image {
    height: 600px;
    height: calc(100vh - 15vmax);
    max-height: 75vh;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, yes it was a child element purely so it could be in the position it is with ease. Completely passed my mind. Thank you!

Comment: Been trying… not letting me for 2 minutes I think it said :) @MihailMinkov

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your site.